# How do I restrict date range in bootstrap calendar plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Hopefully, this post is in the right place.

[image]

I'm using **[bootstrap calendar](https://github.com/Serhioromano/bootstrap-calendar)** plugin. How to restrict the **previous and next** range button in the bootstrap calendar? 
So far as I am aware, the `prev/next` triggers should place near to [calendar.js](https://github.com/Serhioromano/bootstrap-calendar/blob/master/js/calendar.js).

Here is the code I have so far in `calendar.js`:

```
Calendar.prototype.navigate = function(where, next) {
        var to = $.extend({}, this.options.position);
        if(where == 'next') {
            switch(this.options.view) {
                case 'year':
                    to.start.setFullYear(this.options.position.start.getFullYear() + 1);
                    break;
                case 'month':
                    to.start.setMonth(this.options.position.start.getMonth() + 1);
                    break;
                case 'week':
                    to.start.setDate(this.options.position.start.getDate() + 7);
                    break;
                case 'day':
                    to.start.setDate(this.options.position.start.getDate() + 1);
                    break;
            }
        } else if(where == 'prev') {
            switch(this.options.view) {
                case 'year':
                    to.start.setFullYear(this.options.position.start.getFullYear() - 1);
                    break;
                case 'month':
                    to.start.setMonth(this.options.position.start.getMonth() - 1);
                    break;
                case 'week':
                    to.start.setDate(this.options.position.start.getDate() - 7);
                    break;
                case 'day':
                    to.start.setDate(this.options.position.start.getDate() - 1);
                    break;
            }
        }
```

I added `today` as a **[pivot](http://140.123.241.103/se07/IntroISS.php?lang=en-US)** to this section in `calendar.js`:

```
else if(where == 'today') {
    // to.start.setTime(new Date().getTime());
    // Sunday 15 July, 2018
    var moonLanding = new Date('July 15, 2018 00:00:00 GMT+00:00');
    to.start.setTime(moonLanding.getTime());
}
```

Is there any way to limit date range?

Answer (score 1):

You can set your own options when initiating the calendar and do some validation logic by using the customized options in `Calendar.prototype.navigate`, like

```
$("#calendar").calendar({
    limitStart: new Date("2017-01-01"),
    limitEnd: new Date("2019-01-01")
});

# in Calendar.prototype.navigate, use them as this.options.limitStart, this.options.limitEnd
```